# Rails array of images -- create links that will display the next/prev images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, orbit

I'm still a Rails beginner, and still have a lot to learn.

Currently, I can display all the images at once, no problem:

```
<!-- For the Thumbnail strip -->
<% @examples.each do |e| %>
    <ul class="example-grid"><%= e.description %></ul>
    <% if e.image.url != "/images/original/missing.png"  %>
        <p><%= image_tag e.image.url, size: "200x200" %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I want to first show the image of `@examples[0]` and from there, have two `link_to` or `button_to` paths to show `@example[current + 1]`.  Something like that.

How does this work?

Comment: This is no image in your last block of markup?

Comment: Yes I know -- that's eventually what I want to do  to show the images via Orbit :). Now, I'm wondering how can I click through the pictures (next and previous) via links

Comment: The question is a bit vague. There are too many options. Simple prev/next links mean the pages are shown in separate pages. You may want to show them by JS slider, and there are further options for preload or not and there are too many solutions. Simply put, you need View, Controller, a pagination gem, JS lib to work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Sliders, image slide show plugins
[Image Slide show demo link](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/581/previous-next-slideshow-simple-and-practical-image-slideshow-jQuery-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

try bootstrap carousel and genertate the html like you are doing now:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <% @examples.each_with_index do |e, index| %>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<%= index %>" class="<%= if e.primary ? "active" : "" %>></li>
  </ol>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <% @examples.each do |e| %>
    <div class="item active">
<% if e.image.url != "/images/original/missing.png"  %>
    <p><%= image_tag e.image.url, size: "200x200" %></p>
<% end %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @ovatsug25 can you break down this line for me? I don't get what's happening:  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<%= index %>" class="<%= if e.primary ? "active" : "" %>>